# How do I convert a field in seconds into days:hours:seconds in ibm db2 sql?

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 date fields which returns the seconds using the query below:

```
SELECT
  id,
  targetdate,
  actualdate,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(2, CHAR (TIMESTAMP(actualdate) - TIMESTAMP(targetdate))) AS difference
FROM mytable;
```

This returns the seconds between the 2 dates. I need this displayed as, 1 Day 3 hours (example). Is there any function in db2 that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Datetime operations and durations](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=expressions-datetime-operations-durations):

> **timestamp duration**
> A number of years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds, and fractional seconds, expressed as a DECIMAL(14+s,s) number, where s is
> the number of digits of fractional seconds ranging from 0 to 12. To be
> properly interpreted, the number must have the format
> yyyymmddhhmmss.nnnnnnnnnnnn, where yyyy, mm, dd, hh, mm, ss, and
> nnnnnnnnnnnn represent, respectively, the number of years, months,
> days, hours, minutes, seconds, and fractional seconds. The result of
> subtracting one timestamp value from another is a timestamp duration,
> with scale that matches the maximum timestamp precision of the
> timestamp operands.

> **Timestamp arithmetic**
>
> Timestamps can be subtracted, incremented, or decremented.
>
> **The result of subtracting one timestamp (TS2) from another (TS1) is a timestamp duration that specifies the number of years, months,
> days, hours, minutes, seconds, and fractional seconds between the two
> timestamps.** The data type of the result is DECIMAL(14+s,s), where s is
> the maximum timestamp precision of TS1 and TS2.

Example assuming that you don't need fractions of second:

```
WITH A (TS1, TS2) AS 
(
  VALUES 
  (
    CURRENT TIMESTAMP
  , CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 1 YEAR - 2 MONTH - 3 DAY - 4 HOUR - 5 MINUTE - 6 SECOND
  )
)
SELECT 
  TS1, TS2, D
,  SUBSTR (D,  1, 4) || ' YEARS '
|| SUBSTR (D,  5, 2) || ' MONTHS '
|| SUBSTR (D,  7, 2) || ' DAYS '
|| SUBSTR (D,  9, 2) || ' HOURS '
|| SUBSTR (D, 11, 2) || ' MINUTES '
|| SUBSTR (D, 13, 2) || ' SECONDS '
    AS STRING
FROM
(
  SELECT TS1, TS2, DIGITS (DEC (TS1 - TS2, 14)) AS D
  FROM A
) B
```

| TS1 | TS2 | D | STRING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-02-17.38.55.282000 | 2021-05-30-13.33.49.282000 | 00010203040506 | 0001 YEARS 02 MONTHS 03 DAYS 04 HOURS 05 MINUTES 06 SECONDS |